# How do I find the new center of a rotated rectangle for character collision? Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry, rectangles

I have been programming a myriad of character animations with changing colliders for a 2D Unity game, but am having trouble figuring out how to find the new center of a rotated rectangle for a prone animation. Rotating the rectangle isn't an issue, as I've simply set the current length of the rectangle as its new width, and vice versa. The problem is that my new rectangle falls to the ground because its center (or "offset," as Unity calls it) is the same as the default collider; it's briefly in the air when I press my prone button.

Basically, I want the following to happen in my game:

1. My character stands upright with his default rectangle collider, which collides with the ground due to gravity.
2. I press a button, and the rectangle is reassigned values so that it appears to be rotated 90 degrees, but its new center makes it so that my character remains touching the ground the entire time.

Here's a graphic that hopefully explains things better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYgcp.jpg

I was able to program a crouch animation using similar logic, but cannot wrap my head around how to apply it to this scenario. Here's that successful piece of code:

```
    boxCollider.size = new Vector2(boxCollider.size.x, boxCollider.size.y * .5f);
    boxCollider.offset = new Vector2(boxCollider.offset.x, boxCollider.offset.y - (boxCollider.size.y * .5f));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this?

exchange dimensions:

```
boxCollider.size = new Vector2(boxCollider.size.y, boxCollider.size.x);
```

set new center height as half-height of new rectangle (staying x the same):

```
 boxCollider.offset = new Vector2(boxCollider.offset.x, boxCollider.size.y * .5f);
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this produces the second result in the image I linked.

Comment: OK, what does `offset` field exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MBo for helping me rethink this a bit. The answer is actually very similar to the code I posted earlier.

```
    boxCollider.size = new Vector2(boxCollider.size.y, boxCollider.size.x);
    boxCollider.offset = new Vector2(boxCollider.offset.x, boxCollider.offset.y - (boxCollider.size.y * .5f));
```

This sets the new rectangle center correctly, and of course can be easily reversed when the player stands up again.

Comment: I should note this only works for rectangles with a length that is twice the size of the width.